# Cookie is not being set when deploy to netlify

Tags: reactjs, cookies, netlify

Hi I'm deploying a react app to netlify but I have a weird issue : my cookie is not being set. I use an api host on heroku and react-cookie to store the JWT in the cookie. When I'm running on local the cookie is being set there is no problem but when I deploy the app on netlify nothing happen but I get the JWT correctly just the cookie is not created/set. Literraly nothing happen. I have search and I found this link : [Setting Cookies on react](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/01/19/setting-cookies-in-react/). So react-cookie seems to works on netlify so I don't understant why is not working here.

Here is my code who set the cookie

```
function getCookie(token: string){
    console.log(token);
    setCookies('jid', token, {path: '/'});
    console.log(cookies);
  }
```

When I run that code on local I see my cookie but on netlify I correctly see my token sent by the api but I get an empty object when I print the value of cookies. Even in the Application tab there is nothing

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the App component who set the cookie but I don't think it come from there otherwise it wouldn't work on local too

```
import "./App.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./pages/home";
import { Navbar } from "./components/navbar";
import { Login } from "./pages/login";
import { Signup } from "./pages/signup";
import { Dashboard } from "./pages/dashboard";
import { useState } from "react";
import { CookiesProvider } from "react-cookie";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

export const App = () => {
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [cookies, setCookies, removeCookie] = useCookies(['jid']);

  function getCookie(value: string){
    console.log(value);
    setCookies('jid', value, {path: '/'});
    console.log(cookies);
  }

  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <Router>
        <header style={{ boxShadow: "0 2px 8px #f0f1f2" }}>
          <Navbar isAuth={isAuth} setAuth={setAuth} removeCookie={removeCookie}/>
        </header>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login setAuth={setAuth} setCookie={getCookie}/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup">
            <Signup setAuth={setAuth} setCookie={getCookie}/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard isAuth={isAuth} setAuth={setAuth} removeCookie={removeCookie}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: where is that setCookies coming from?

Comment: setCookie come from react-cookie I will put the code of the App component to have a better view